# How to use a WHILE loop in PL/SQL with decrementing

Tags: plsql

I've been trying to do a lot of research on this problem I need to do for a class, but I'm not having much luck. IE, I can't find a good example. I'm an example person.

Create a PL/SQL block that uses a WHILE loop structure to generate a payment schedule for a donor's pledge, which is to be paid monthly in equal increments. Values available for the block are starting payment due date, monthly payment amount, and number of total monthly payments for the pledge. The list that is generated should display a line for each monthly payment showing payment number, date due, payment amount and donation balance (remaining amount of pledge owed).

Instead of displaying the donation balance on each line of output, display the total paid to date.

After some consideration, it's obvious that the payments have to be decremented on a monthly basis until the balance is zero at which the loop will exit. But I am not sure how to do it properly. I've looked all over the Internet and there's nothing that seems to help me finish the pl/sql block, example wise.

This is what I have so far.

```
declare
lv_paymentnumber_num number(3,0);
lv_paymentamount_num number(4,2);
lv_datepaymentpaid_date date;
lv_amountpaidtodate_num number(4,2);
lv_balanceremaining_num number(4,2);
lv_nextduedate_date date;
begin
lv_balanceremaining_num :-lv_paymentamount_num - lv_amountpaidtodate_num;
dbms_output.put_line(lv_balanceremaining_num);
loop
```

after that, that's where I get lost.

Comment: Are you not sure how to construct a loop which exits once the balance reaches zero?

Answer (score 1):

To terminate a loop use the `EXIT` statement as demonstrated below:

```
declare
  lv_paymentnumber_num number(3,0) := 0;
  lv_paymentamount_num number(4,2);
  lv_datepaymentpaid_date date;
  lv_amountpaidtodate_num number(4,2);
  lv_balanceremaining_num number(4,2);
  lv_nextduedate_date date;
  nPayment  NUMBER;
begin
  loop 
    nPayment := LEAST(lv_paymentamount_num, lv_balanceremaining_num);
    lv_balanceremaining_num := lv_balanceremaining_num - nPayment;
    lv_amountpaidtodate_num := lv_amountpaidtodate_num + nPayment;
    lv_paymentnumber_num := lv_paymentnumber_num + 1;

    dbms_output.put_line('Payment = ' || nPayment ||
                         '  Balance remaining = ' ||
                         lv_balanceremaining_num);

    IF lv_balanceremaining_num <= 0 THEN
      EXIT;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Amend as needed.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06550: line 12, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "LV_BALANCEREMAINING_NUM" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_
   LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_
The symbol ";" was substituted for "LV_BALANCEREMAINING_NUM" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: The first line in the loop is not terminated with ";"

Comment: One could argue that `exit when lv_balanceremaining_num <= 0;` is easier to read but this solution is totally fine.